# Replace a 6v synch. motor with a 12v synch. motor in holiday decoration

Tags: 12v

I have a Santa fibre optic decoration that has a TYC-30 AC6V 5RPM (.8-1W) synch. motor that's very noisy so I want to replace it.  I can't seem to source a 6V version of this motor from the inter-webs.  So my question is can I put a TYC-30 AC12V 5RPM in its place or will it simply not even run?  The Santa's AC Adapter's output is 6VAC 1A 6W.

I wasn't sure if the 12V rating on the motor was an "Up to" 12V or "Requires 12V" to run.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does the data sheet say? For the most part, the 12V is nominal motor voltage. You can give it a bit more or less, but it will run faster or slower. And at some voltage less than its nominal, it will stall out. So **It depends**.

Comment: Passerby, I'll try to dig up a data sheet on it, but did just notice the 12V AC motor said "operates at 10-12V", so sounds like 6V will stall it.

Comment: it's not going to run slow.  it's a synchronous motor, it runs at line frequency.

Answer (score 1):

a synchronous motor will have lower torque at reduced voltage, if the load is light enough it will work, if it is not the motor won't move.